# Are inserts with sequence numbers nextval atomic for this number?

Tags: oracle, sequence

If I am inserting rows into a table in auto-commit mode where one column is defined by a sequence's nextval value, are these values guaranteed to become visible in the order they are inserted? I am wondering if a scenario where from three concurrent connections:

1. Inserts foo
2. Inserts bar
3. Select all, observes bar with sequence number 2 but not foo with sequence number 1.

is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Auto-commit" is not a concept of the Oracle database.  That is, there is no "auto-commit" mode or feature in the database -- it is only implemented in tools (like SQL*Plus).

A tool can implement "auto-commit" in different ways, but in most cases, it's probably along the lines of this:

```
(user's command, e.g., INSERT INTO ...)
<success response from Oracle server>
COMMIT;
```

In this case, the COMMIT does not get issued by the tool until there is a positive response from the server that the user's command has been executed.  In a networked environment with >10ms latency, plus the vagaries of multithreading on the Oracle server itself, I would say there *could* be situations where session #2's automatic `COMMIT` gets processed on the server before session #1's and that, therefore, it is possible for session #3 to observe "bar" but not "foo".

The `COMMIT` timing of each session relative to the time at which session #3 starts its query is the only thing that matters.  Session #3 will see whatever work session #1 and/or session #2 have committed as of the time session #3's query starts.

Answer (score 2):

The Oralce sequences are thread safe and are always created in order. It is guaranteed that the numbers produced are unique.

But you might not see an insert of an other session immediatley, if this other session has still an open transaction. This might create a temporary gap in the sequence you are seeing from SELECTs.

Further more, if a transaction which has called NEXTVAL is rolled back, then this will cause permanent gaps in the sequence. Sequences are not affected by roll backs or commits. An increment is always immediate and definitive.

See: [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) (Oracle Help Center)

Comment: The above scenario can happen, so to speak? Gaps would not matter much but if a select would observe a higher number before a lower one, I am in trouble. In this case, I guess that I need to lock the table before inserting.

Comment: This would not really help, as the other session can still get the next number before you lock the table, but insert it only after you commit!

Comment: As long as I make it a requirement that the application having access to the database locks the table from each thread before attempting to update any rows, I should be good, shouldn't I?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. [LOCK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm), get NEXTVAL, INSERT, commit.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter What problem are you trying to address?

Comment: I have a table containing events with incrementing ids. Events can be added by multiple processes. Any consumer remembers the last id it observed and only queries for the events after. Therefore, observing bar without foo would be a problem as events must not be missed.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter If you lock the table, then you are serializing your whole processing. You may as well do it in a single thread.

Comment: I could but there is a lot of preprocessing done, the insert is one of the cheapest parts, it would overcomplicate the software.

Comment: *"are always created in order"* - no, this is not guaranteed unless you explicitly specify the `ORDERED` sequence attribute.

Comment: The Oracle doc says: *"If you specify none of the following clauses, then you create an ascending sequence that starts with 1 and increases by 1 [...]"* and *"ORDER is necessary only to guarantee ordered generation if you are using Oracle Real Application Clusters."*